# Getting upcoming Games in LOL with C#

Tags: c#, .net

briefly my problem: I'm trying to get future LOL games (preferably with GameID). I have already tried several APIs (Riotsharp etc.) and the only useful one I have found is PandaScore. I'm probably just making a small mistake, but no matter how I change the parameters in the sample code on the website, I only ever get error messages.
Maybe someone has worked with Pandascore before or had a similar problem and can help me.
Thanks in advance

The code the docs provide:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.pandascore.co/lol/matches/upcoming?sort=&page=1&per_page=50"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "accept", "application/json" },
        { "authorization", "Bearer /*My API Key, generated at PandaScore*/" },
    },
};
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting.

Comment: As mentioned, I get different error messages. Mostly 404 and 401 errors. If I copy the code one to one from the docs, paste my key, I get 401. I also generated new keys and tried them, everything should be ok with my account etc., so i do not really understand the 401 exception.

Comment: In RapidApi.com Pandascore is also listed and you can test the endpoints, but you also always get a 404 error. If you try the code yourself, exactly the same result.

Comment: Have you tested it with porsman?

Comment: Not pretty sure what you mean by that. Can you explain it a little bit further for me?